# Priority ThreadPoolExecutor in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to make an ThreadPoolExecutor with priority. So I define a

```
private static ThreadPoolExecutor threadpool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(30, MAXPOOL,  MAXPOOL, TimeUnit.SECONDS,  
     queue, new mThreadFactory());
```

So the key is the queue reference now. But when I declare :

```
static PriorityBlockingQueue<mDownloadThread> queue=new PriorityBlockingQueue<mDownloadThread>(MAXPOOL,new DownloadThreadComparator());
```

The compiler gives an error in the first line: **The constructor ThreadPoolExecutor(int, int, int, TimeUnit, PriorityBlockingQueue, FileAccess.mThreadFactory) is undefined** with a single quickfix: *Change type of 'queue' to BlockingQueue*. Can you help me to understand whats the problem?

Thanks

Additional Info:

For comparing the runnables I implementd the following class

```
class mDownloadThread implements Runnable{      
    private Runnable mRunnable;     
    private int priority;       
    mDownloadThread(Runnable runnable){
        mRunnable=runnable;         
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRunnable.run();        
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }       
}
```

The comparator:

```
class DownloadThreadComparator implements Comparator<mDownloadThread>{
    @Override
    public int compare(mDownloadThread arg0, mDownloadThread arg1) {

    if (arg0==null && arg1==null){
        return 0;
    } else if (arg0==null){
        return -1;
    } else if (arg1==null){
        return 1;
    }
    return arg0.getPriority()-arg1.getPriority();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor accepts `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` and not `BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable>`, thus you can't pass to it `PriorityBlockingQueue<mDownloadThread>` instance.

You can change type of `queue` to `PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>`, but in that case you won't be able to implement `Comparator<mDownloadThread>` without casting inside the `compare` method.

The other solution is to bypass generic type-checking but it would be your responsibility to submit only instances of `mDownloadThread` to `execute` method:

```
static ThreadPoolExecutor threadpool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(30, MAXPOOL, 
        MAXPOOL, TimeUnit.SECONDS, (PriorityBlockingQueue) queue, new mThreadFactory());
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `ThreadPoolExecutor` is expecting a `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` and you are passing a `PriorityBlockingQueue<mDownloadThread>`. The `PriorityBlockingQueue` implements `BlockingQueue` so that is not the problem. The problem is the `Runnable`. You cannot pass a generic type of `mDownloadThread` where `Runnable` was expected.

Fix is the following:

```
static PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue=new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(MAXPOOL,new DownloadThreadComparator());
```

&&

```
class DownloadThreadComparator implements Comparator<Runnable>{
```

If `ThreadPoolExecutor` were written to accept a `BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable>` what you have would work.

Comment: mDownloadThread implements Runnable also. so it shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: No. Just like you can't pass a `List<String>` into a `List<Object>`

Comment: Doing this passes instances of FutureTask into the Comparator. This is legal because it extends from Runnable. You can't get at the attributes necessary for a comparison of the object in question, though. Real pain in the butt.