# Extending interfaces and conversion errors in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a "PriorityThreadPoolExecutor".

So I declare the Executor:

```
static ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool =  
                new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 100, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
```

And the key for the prioritization is the queue paramether. Basically I need a PriorityBlockingQueue so I use the constructor:

```
PriorityBlockingQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator);
queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<mRunnable>(10,
        new Comparator<mRunnable>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(mRunnable lhs, mRunnable rhs) {
                return rhs.getPriority()-lhs.getPriority();
            }
        });
```

Where the mRunnable is:

```
public interface mRunnable extends Runnable {
    public int getPriority();
}
```

But here the compiler complains:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from PriorityBlockingQueue<mRunnable> 
       to PriorityBlockingQueue <Runnable>
```

I do not understand why is this error happening when mRunnable extends Runnable.

I could patch it changing the comparator:

```
new Comparator<Runnable>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Runnable lhs, Runnable rhs) {
        if (lhs instanceof mRunnable && rhs instanceof mRunnable){
        return ((mRunnable)rhs).getPriority()-((mRunnable)lhs).getPriority();
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

But this is a ugly sollution imho.

Can you explain why is the Type mismatch is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type mismatch is happening because of different Generic types, you should change your reference type from `PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>` to `PriorityBlockingQueue <mRunnable>`.
Or `PriorityBlockingQueue<? extends Runnable>` for example.

Comment: then is the constructor of the threadpoolexecutor who complains =(

Comment: Yeah .. I see now. It is known issue, you can also check these links for workarounds:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545623/how-to-implement-priorityblockingqueue-with-threadpoolexecutor-and-custom-tasks/5485769#5485769
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792767/priority-threadpoolexecutor-in-java-android