# AsyncTask on Executor and PriorityBlockingQueue implementation issue

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, priority-queue

On the wave of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039596/asynctask-on-executor-and-priorityblockingqueue) and with many hints from [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792767/priority-threadpoolexecutor-in-java-android), I'm trying to implement an `AsyncTask` variant with tasks that can be prioritized.

In my `CustomAsyncTask` class I have:

```
public abstract class CustomAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    private static int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 1;
    private static int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 1;

    private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

    private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
        private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return new Thread(r, "CustomAsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
        }
    };

    private static final BlockingQueue<DownloadTask> pPoolWorkQueue =
            new PriorityBlockingQueue<DownloadTask>(10, new DownloadTasksComparator());

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static Executor PRIORITY_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
            = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS, (PriorityBlockingQueue) pPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);

   //...
}
```

The comparator:

```
public class DownloadTasksComparator implements Comparator<DownloadTask> {

    @Override
    public int compare(DownloadTask arg0, DownloadTask arg1) {
        int res;

        if (arg0 == null && arg1 == null) {
            res = 0;
        } else if (arg0 == null) {
            res = -1;
        } else if (arg1 == null) {
            res = 1;
        }

        res = arg0.getPriority() - arg1.getPriority();

        return res;
    }
}
```

In the `DownloadTask` class extending `CustomAsyncTask` I have a `priority` Integer field and a `getPriority()` method.

I'm calling the tasks execution as:

```
DownloadTask dt = new DownloadTask(..., PRIORITY_NORMAL, ...);
dt.executeOnExecutor(CustomAsyncTask.PRIORITY_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

This works: if the pool sizes are 1, the downloads get executed one by one; if pool size is 2, etc.

note: priority Integers have arbitrary values:

```
public static final int PRIORITY_HIGH = 10;
public static final int PRIORITY_NORMAL = 1;
```

But if I call the tasks as:

```
DownloadTask dt = new DownloadTask(..., PRIORITY_HIGH, ...);
dt.executeOnExecutor(CustomAsyncTask.PRIORITY_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

I have a `java.lang.ClassCastException: my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask$3 cannot be cast to my.pkg.name.DownloadTask`

and then

```
at my.pkg.name.DownloadTasksComparator.compare(DownloadTasksComparator.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.siftUpUsingComparator(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:447)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1295)
at my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(CustomAsyncTask.java:494)
at my.pkg.name.GetDownloadTaskListener$1.finishDownload(GetDownloadTaskListener.java:180)
at my.pkg.name.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:330)
at my.pkg.name.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:1)
at my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask.finish(CustomAsyncTask.java:536)
at my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask.access$0(CustomAsyncTask.java:532)
at my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(CustomAsyncTask.java:549)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

all from `AndroidRuntime`

I really don't have a clue...

**EDIT**: At this point, I've wrapped a small Eclipse project that implements things exactly the same way of the bigger application and suffers from the same issue. It borrows `CustomAsyncTaskComparator` and `CustomAsyncTask` verbatim. No visual feedback is given. The app's progress is just some LogCat output. But it gives the idea. When more than two tasks are enqueued, the app FCs.

**https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrg4kscgw3f1xwr/ConcurrentTest.tar.gz**

Comment: Where in the code are you getting that exception?

Comment: it says line 1 of Comparator class. Happens as soon as a download with high priority wants to start while there's a low priority one already in queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have noticed while looking through the `AsyncTask` implementation, it internally uses a `FutureTask` to handle the background task, and that is what gets handed on to the `Executor` and potentially queued on it's work queue. Since you are already deriving your own implementation, you could replace the `FutureTask` with a custom derivative that holds a reference to the `AsyncTask`, to be accessed from your `Comparator` implementation.

Also, instead of replacing the default static `Executor` of your custom `AsyncTask` derivative, you should instead use the `executeOnExecutor()` method in your subclasses so that it can be used in a generic manner.

Comment: Hello and thanks, but I'm sorry I don't know how to proceed in regards of `replace the FutureTask with a custom derivative that holds a reference to the AsyncTask`. 2nd paragraph: I tried supplying a fresh defined `Executor` instead of making a custom AsyncTask class, but the result it's the same: a class cast exception.

Comment: @dentex: I meant that you should implement a custom class extending `FutureTask` that will hold a reference to the `AsyncTask` that will be using it, thus providing a way for the `AsyncTask` and it's properties to be accessed from the `Comparator` implementations that will be passed the `FutureTask`.

Comment: I've posted a link to a test project (see Question). Would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: @dentex: Did you try implementing my suggestion?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's out of my league... (as the time being)

Comment: @dentex: Ok, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mty066xqz09is2b/ConcurrentTestPatch.patch)'s a working patch that implements my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much... This is beautiful. Thanks for giving me this opportunity. Next app's version credits will have a Contributor! :)

Comment: LoL!!! every Comparator's `arg0` must be swapped with `arg1`. Eheheh! Great. I Finally had the chance to notice this. It was giving the opposite comparison result. :)

Answer (score 2):

`CustomAsyncTask`, like `AsyncTask`, uses a `static` queue. *Everything* that goes on that queue, at present, will run through your `DownloadTasksComparator`. However, `DownloadTasksComparator` only works with `DownloadTask`. So long as you only use `DownloadTask`, and not other subclasses of `CustomAsyncTask`, you will be fine. However, apparently you have some other anonymous inner class extending `CustomAsyncTask`, and that's not a `DownloadTask`.

Make `CustomAsyncTask` be `abstract`, with a `getPriority()` method as an `abstract` method. Rename `DownloadTasksComparator` to `CustomAsyncTaskComparator` and have it compare `CustomAsyncTask` instances. Then, your other subclasses of `CustomAsyncTask` would need to implement their own `getPriority()` methods, to enable them to be sorted along with the `DownloadTask` instances in your work queue.

Comment: Hello. It's not the case as you suggest in 1st paragraph, because `DownloadTask` class it's the only one extending the abstract class `CustomAsyncTask`. Anyway, I followed your instructions in 2nd paragraph, and now, as before, as soon as the comparator is called into the scene, I get the weird `java.lang.ClassCastException: my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask$3 cannot be cast to my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask` :-O the only difference seems to be that `$3`

Comment: @dentex: "because DownloadTask class it's the only one extending the abstract class CustomAsyncTask" -- not according to the stack trace. The `PriorityBlockingQueue` is comparing a `DownloadTask` to something else using `DownloadTasksComparator`. Now, it could be that you are putting other stuff on `pPoolWorkQueue` not shown here, but if `CustomAsyncTask` is otherwise a straight-up port of `AsyncTask`, then `my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask$3` is a non-static inner class of `CustomAsyncTask` that extends `CustomAsyncTask`.

Comment: May this be happening because `DownloadTask` is defined in its own class: `public class DownloadTask extends CustomAsyncTask <Void, Integer, Long> { ... }` with inside the public method `public DownloadTask(Context context, int priority, ...) { ... }` ? This is where I have `this.mPriority = priority` in order for the method `getPriority()` returning `mPriority` to work. Then I call the `DownloadTask dt = ...` as I show into the Question. I mean, do I have to make the `DownloadTask` class an inner class?

Comment: @dentex: Wait a moment... `java.lang.ClassCastException: my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask$3 cannot be cast to my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask` indicates that the `$3` inner class is *not* a `CustomAsyncTask`. Are you accidentally putting something else into `pPoolWorkQueue`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... It's a bit frustrating. So let me dig a bit more into threading in general, because this is starting to be a little "blind-trials-and-blind-errors" like. One last thing: could the cast `(PriorityBlockingQueue) pPoolWorkQueue` inside the `Executor` be the problem? Because it would accept `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. It doesn't compile without this cast, as seen on http://stackoverflow.com/a/7792813/1865860.

Comment: @dentex: "One last thing: could the cast (PriorityBlockingQueue) pPoolWorkQueue inside the Executor be the problem?" -- I wouldn't think so.

Comment: As I mention in my answer, the inner class is actually an instance of `FutureTask` that `AsyncTask` uses internally for it's asynchronous operation, as it does not implement `Runnable` itself.

Comment: I've posted a link to a test project (see Question). Would be great if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `PriorityBlockingQueue<CustomAsyncTask>` you use to construct the ThreadPoolExecutor. ThreadPoolExecutor should accept `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`. ThreadPoolExecutor uses this queue to queue the runnables (runnables are submitted by calling `execute(Runnable r)`).

In AsyncTask's case, it calls `Executor.execute(Runnable r)` with a FutureTask object, so it's this FutureTask object being queued by the executor, not AsyncTask itself. So when the comparator tries to cast runnable to DownloadTask, the exception is thrown. I guess `my.pkg.name.CustomAsyncTask$3` may be an inner runnable class.

Here is part of the source code of AsyncTask:

```
public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(Executor exec,
        Params... params) {
    if (mStatus != Status.PENDING) {
        switch (mStatus) {
            case RUNNING:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot execute task:"
                        + " the task is already running.");
            case FINISHED:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot execute task:"
                        + " the task has already been executed "
                        + "(a task can be executed only once)");
        }
    }

    mStatus = Status.RUNNING;

    onPreExecute();

    mWorker.mParams = params;
    exec.execute(mFuture);

    return this;
}
```

If you're trying to run AsyncTask with priority using this PriorityBlockingQueue approach, you should subclass the runnable object passed to the execute method, making it with a priority. You are using a custom asynctask, so you have full control of the variables.

To those trying to run the original AsyncTask with priority, i don't think there are much can be done. AsyncTask "execute" a private member variable `mFuture`, your hands are tied.

I am currently working on a similar problem, but in my case the "priority" is the timestamp, and i can set it in the runnable implementation, so it's kind of unrestricted by AsyncTask.

This is my code, just in case it might help someone. Sorry for my poor English!

```
/* Executor used by AsyncTask. Use it with executeOnExecutor()*/
class PriorityExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor{

    //workQueue is a instance of PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>
    public PriorityExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
            long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,threadFactory);

    }

    //wrap the runnable passed in.
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        super.execute(new PriorityRunnableWrapper(command));
    }
}

//a wrapper class
class PriorityRunnableWrapper implements Runnable ,Comparable<PriorityRunnableWrapper>{

    long addedTime;//the "priority"
    Runnable r;

    public PriorityRunnableWrapper(Runnable r){
        this.r = r;
        addedTime = System.nanoTime();//in my case the timestamp is the priority
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        r.run();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PriorityRunnableWrapper another) {
        if(addedTime == another.addedTime)return 0;
        return addedTime - another.addedTime > 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }

}
```